# Oveloading the ostream << operator for a sequence

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, ostream

I would like to define the operator << to operate on a sequence of elements, in a way like the STL algorithms work, by taking as arguments the first and last element of a container. As opposed to taking only one argument, the container itself, e.g.

```
std::ostream& operator<< ( std::ostream &out, std::list inList );
```

So that I would only have to write one function that would work regardless of if I am using list, vector, array, etc. And I would have to call the function with two arguments, inList.begin() and inList.end()

The problem is that operator<< takes only one argument. What is the best way to overcome this?

EDIT: Thank you for your answers. I should probably have made it more clear that I would prefer to have the ability to print a range of elements, including possibly a subsequence of a container (again, like STL algorithms). E.g. if a vector v has 5 elements, I wish could print them all giving a sequence from v.begin() to v.end() with an output like this:

```
[element1 element2 element3 element4 element5]
```

But I wish I also could print the first three only, in the range [v.begin(), v.begin()+3)

```
[element1 element2 element3]
```

Would your suggested answers work in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get away from passing one argument, but you want something to work with any kind of container. So ideally you would want a function like

```
template <typename T>
std::ostream& someFunction(std::ostream& out, T first, T last) {
  // do your stuff
}
```

and an `ostream& operator<<` looking *something* like

```
template <T>
std::ostream& << (std::ostream& out, const T& sequence) {
  return someFunction(out, sequence.begin(), sequence.end());
}
```

However, this operator will clash with predefined ones, so you cannot just implement it like that. Fortunately you can play some template magic to get around this, and to see a very nice solution, check out [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850473/pretty-print-c-stl-containers) and the corresponding [github project](http://louisdx.github.com/cxx-prettyprint/)

Note that since (presumably) the objective is to have a generic `ostream& operator<<` for containers, and you would achieve this via a function template, it is not essential to have the function take iterators. It could also work taking a (const) reference to the container.

Answer (score 1):

Pass only one argument, and take `begin` and `end` inside of the method. All std containers have `begin` and `end`. And no, you can't change the number of parameters to `operator <<`.

Comment: 1) Note that one must write a function template, not a function. 2) Perhaps `std::begin()`, `std::end()` would be even better?

Comment: @Robᵩ 1) Probably 2) Don't see why... does it have support on major compilers?

Comment: 2) Because `std::begin()` has specializations for arrays in addition to `std::` containers.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but I had to address the same issue recently so thought I'd post my solution here. Range and makeRange duplicate the functionality of std::pair and std::make_pair, but I added the former just to avoid conflicts (other types of pairs may be printed differently).

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename Iterator>
struct Range
{
  Range();
  Range(Iterator begin_, Iterator end_) : begin(begin_), end(end_) {}

  Iterator begin, end;
};

template <typename Iterator>
Range<Iterator>
makeRange(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
{
  return Range<Iterator>(begin, end);
}

template <typename InputIterator>
ostream &
operator<<(ostream & out, Range<InputIterator> const & range)
{
  for (InputIterator iter = range.begin; iter != range.end; ++iter)
  {
    if (iter != range.begin) out << ", ";  // adjust formatting to taste
    out << *iter;
  }

  return out;
}

int
main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
  cout << makeRange(a, a + 2) << endl;  // prints 1, 2
}
```